# SQL query to help transpose data

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm trying to write a SQL query to transpose the data into a new column, I've done some research with pivot, but I'm not sure I understand how to use it properly, or maybe I shouldn't be using that and the query can be written in a different format. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you know which MyValue to put in which column?

Comment: Are you indicating you need to change the schema of a table in the DB without losing data, OR is Table 1 the result of a query and you'd ideally like it as your "Desired result" table?

Comment: not the schema, correct is the result of a query and would like the desired result....@jarlh, essentially every serial has 2 rows and i want to move the second one (externald = 47) into a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
select serial,
       MAX(case when externalID <> 47 then MyValues end) as MyValues,
       MAX(case when externalID = 47 then MyValues end) as NuwColumn
from mytable
group by serial
```

This code works on major databases such as `mysql` and `postgresql`...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @SelVazi version (because I hate aggregating functions):

```
SELECT t1.[Serial], t1.[MyValues], t2.[MyValues] AS [NewColumn] 
FROM [Table1] t1
    INNER JOIN [Table1] t2
    ON t1.Serial = t2.Serial 
    WHERE t1.ExternalID = 43 AND t2.ExternalID = 47
```

(NOTE: this is an MS SQL Server version)

Comment: thank you, both are valid answers. I wish I could mark both as such :)